# Що означає слово "понаглятися"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

Вчора почув таку фразу "Понагляйтеся до нас, тут є...", однак пошуки в СУМі таких слів як "понаглятися" та "наглятися" не дали ніяких результатів. З контексту я зрозумів, що це щось накшталт "завітайте", однак я не впевнений.
Фраза була почута на Тернопільщині, тому можливо це є галицизм.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я в Інтернеті знайшов лише одне [джерело](http://proridne.com/content/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA/):

> **ПОНАГЛЯТИСЯ** — поспішати

Також є пісня-легенда з ["Історії української літератури"](http://litopys.org.ua/hrushukr/hrush419.htm) Михайла Грушевського, у якому "понагляйся" використовується ніби у контексті "поспішай":

> Бог кличе: «фурмане, горі!
>
> Понагляйся, падь гев скорі!»
>
> «Як я маю горі іти?
>
> Маю жену, маю діти!»

В комедії і 3-х актах ["Така дівка!"](http://carpatho-russian-almanacs.org/LEMKO/LEMKO1940/SuchaGirl.php) в сьомій сцені "понагляйся" також означає "поспішай":

> **Петро**: Завезеш мисс Ружову на станцию, дораз, понагляйся.
>
> **Стефан**: Уж иду, пане Ріпка. **(выходит)**.

Answer (score 3):

Додам ще џерела

[Грінченко](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F&highlight=on)

> **Понагля́тися**, **-ля́юся**, **-єшся**, *гл.* Торопиться, спѣшить. Гол. II. 714.

[Українсько-англійський словник 1955р. (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет)](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F&highlight=on)

> **понагля́ти** (-я́ю, -я́єш) *I vt W.U.* to hurry (hasten, urge, push) on:
>
> - **понагля́ти з робо́тою**, to seek to hasten the work;
> - **понагля́тися** *P vi* to be in a hurry, make haste, speed.

Не знаю, що значить *I vt W.U.*, але схоже, оскільки наявна мітка *діялектізм* в запитанні, на *Western Ukraine*. Наступний словник і згаданий твір „Така дівка“, бо далї підпис *„из житя карпаторусскых емигрант“*, лиш підтверџують цього.

[Словник Лемківскої говірки](//ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/10556/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)

> **понаглятися**, **-наглямся**, **-ляшся**, Пр. Поспішатися, спішитися.

Гадаю, тут можливий вплив Польської мови, порівняйте з корнем слово *наґўи*, а саме [*nagły*](http://wsjp.pl/index.php?id_hasla=20723&id_znaczenia=2180140&l=17&ind=0):

> pojawiający się szybko, niespodziewanie i w sposób zaskakujący

Чи просто якоїсь західної Слов’яньської мови, наприклад [Словацької](https://slovniky.lingea.sk/Anglicko-slovensky/suddenly):

> **suddenly** — ***náhle***, *naraz*, *znenazdania*

Або ж зумовлений невплив [Великої України](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0) в далекі часи.